# How can get Files From Hiideen Folder In Android R

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-11

Hlw Develperos.All are Know About Scoped Storage in Android 11.My Question How i can fetch Data from Hiiden Folder In Android 11 Using Media Store API/

Comment: In the same way as for not hidden folders i think. What did you try?

Comment: And what does this have to do with scoped storage?

Comment: I use Media Store to get Data from Hidden Folder in my External Storage in Android 11.i get aa file from normal Folder but when same query run for Hidden Folder Cursor returns Null

Comment: Well show your code i would say. Dont forget to show which folder. And dont forget to tell how files landed in that folder.

Comment: Please write normal. Dont use a capital for every word.